# Powershell - Hash Table Escape Quotes

Tags: powershell, hash, hashtable, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I would like to retrieve a value associated with a specific item in the hash table TEST
but its not working. Could you help me?

```
$TEST= 
@{"Monday" = "A"; "Tuesday" = "B"; "Wednesday" = "C"; "Thursday" = "D"; "Friday" = "F"}

$Date = Get-Date
$a = $TEST.Get_Item($Date.get_DayOfWeek())

Write-Host $a
```

also try:

```
$TEST= 
@{"Monday" = "A"; "Tuesday" = "B"; "Wednesday" = "C"; "Thursday" = "D"; "Friday" = "F"}

$Date = Get-Date
$a = $Date.get_DayOfWeek()
$b = TEST.Get_Item($a)
```

and:

```
$TEST= 
@{Monday = "A"; Tuesday = "B"; Wednesday = "C"; Thursday = "D"; Friday = "F"}

$Date = Get-Date
$a = $TEST.Get_Item($Date.get_DayOfWeek())

Write-Host $a
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please take a look at the answer provided; Accept or vote-up any that have helped.

Answer (score 2):

DayOfWeek is an object not a string, try this:

```
$TEST[(Get-Date).DayOfWeek.ToString()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you not passing a string to your hash table try something like this:

```
$TEST= 
@{"Monday" = "A"; "Tuesday" = "B"; "Wednesday" = "C"; "Thursday" = "D"; "Friday" = "F"}

$Date = Get-Date
$a = $TEST[""+$Date.get_DayOfWeek()]

Write-Host $a
```